# How to call "on complete" function on jQuery UI selectable?

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery UI like this:

```
$('#theDiv').selectable({
    selected: function() { .... }
});
```

How do I call a function when the selectable thing is done? Just like I can call it in "fadeIn" as an example:

```
$('#theDiv').fadeIn(function() { 
     ... happens on complete... 
});
```

If I call the desired function inside "selected:" the event will appear for every single selected item, I just want it to appear when the selection is done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the `stop` event is what you are looking for.

Quote from jQuery UI

> Triggered at the end of the select operation.

```
$( ".selector" ).selectable({
    stop: function( event, ui ) {}
});
```

Source: http://api.jqueryui.com/selectable/#event-stop